# Is apt-cacher capable of managing packages which are being requested by clients ?

Tags: apt, apt-cacher-ng

I'm currently experimenting with building a repository for our company.
Our only need is ability to control which specific packages are beeing pushed to clients.

We agreed on apt-cacher.

My question is if there is possibility to choose which version of package (if there is more) will be allowed to be downloaded.

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Typically, `apt` (and related tools) will download the latest version of a package, and fail if that version couldn't be downloaded; it won't fall back on older versions.

You might be able to play with the pin priorities with something like

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=trusty-proposed
Pin-Priority: 400
```

This makes `trusty-proposed` have a lesser priority than the other repos (default is 500), and will cause `apt` to pull packages from this pocket only when explicitly requested or when it's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which version when you call `apt-get install`:

```
apt-get install apache2=2.2.20-1ubuntu1
```

You would have to put this in some automatic scripts of some sort which you would get your clients to run, ensuring they get the versions that you want them to.